# Importing location data into Drupal 7

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, location

New to Drupal but am interested in it as an option to transition to from a hand coded site. This site is primarily a location searchable venue index, with venues having various categories.

In Drupal I have set up my content type 'Venue' and have added the location module to store the venue addresses and other contact details.

Now I am wanting to import my existing data which I have ready in a CSV.

To do this I understand I should use the feeds module which I have now installed (along with ctools and job_scheduler).

Now under Structure-> Feeds importers -> Add importer I can create and configure my CSV import - Great!

Unfortunately I can't see any option under Processor to associate my CSV address fields with the location module fields. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

A little late but there's this module: https://drupal.org/project/location_feeds
Location Feeds :D

Haven't actually tried it yet but It seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the feeds module, but i can tell you how we did this. We used the [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module to import a large amount of addresses as locations. With migrate we also had the chance to geocode each location on import ([with the Google Geocoder](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York&sensor=true)). Migrate is a very powerful module which has a lot of possibilities when it comes to importing data to Drupal.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you did it?